# How to monitor all the top level Windows from an inactive Win32 application?

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I am trying to create a Windows Win32 API application which has a requirement to get the Window RECT size of all the overlaying Windows oriented above my App Window.

Currently I am monitoring `WM_ACTIVATE` messages to keep track of when my app windows has another Window placed on top of it. This works fine but there is a hard limitation. It only helps when my app Window is going from "active/foreground"  state to "inactive/background" state. Once it goes to "inactive" state, my app is no longer subscribing to windows messaging. So thereafter, when more windows are opened and my app goes below the Z-counts, I cannot get their handles at all.

What I am looking for is to persistantly get the messaging for the Windows which are opened.

I am currently using `EnumWindows` API to enumerate all the Windows from the active screen. I want to know how can I continually keep track of the other Windows irrespective of my app being active/inactive?

Right now, I am creating my main Window using standard CreateWindow arguments as this:

```
   auto window_type = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
   auto window_ex_type = CW_USEDEFAULT;
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, window_type,
     window_ex_type, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

Comment: A [shell hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registershellhookwindow) can send you a message whenever window activation changes.

Comment: If this is something you need to optimize rendering, keep in mind that even a partially/fully occluded window may need to render itself (e.g. Aero Peek).